# How can I remove a dull spot in a quartz countertop caused by Magic Eraser?

Tags: quartz

I used a Magic Eraser on my quartz to remove a stain and now there is a dull spot. How do you polish it to bring back the shine?

Answer (score 1):

Polishing stones is done by sanding, alternating from rough paper to very fine, from 50 to 3000 grit and water, and is finally polished with a compound paste or wax and a buffer/polisher.  I used to polish acrylic with up to 6000. Your eraser probably acted like a sand paper and the damage depends on its roughness.  Additional sanding may be warrant to smooth it off. You may try first car paint polishing compound sold in most places selling car spray paint and hand polish your spot.  If you have polishing tools it could be more effective and easier, but it all depend on the damage you actually made. If you can still see scratches or dullness after your initial polishing it may mean your eraser was too coarse and you may need to smooth it off and polish again.

Be aware that stones are not impervious to stains. Sealers should be applied where cosmetics or food may come in contact.  You can also buy stone stains remover in most stone tiles retail stores, they are not very expensive and much less damaging than your eraser. Good luck.

Comment: Wouldn't cleaning be a better next step? Magic Eraser is a very soft thing and probably didn't actually dull the finish. It probably just left a residue.

Comment: I was not aware those would leave residues and I presumed you already tried to clean it, my bad.  Of course try this first.

Comment: I would think the magic eraser stripped the glaze or wax it may be as easy as some fresh sealing glaze.

Comment: A magic eraser does act as a mild abrasive.  I really wouldn't doubt that a polishing might be needed to get the gloss back.